# Is the space of polynomial isometric to $\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: functional-analysis, isometry

Consider the space of polynomials of degree $n-1$ defined on $[0,1]$ with $\| p(x)\| = \max_{x\in[0,1]}\vert p(x) \vert$. Is it isometric to $\mathbb R^n$? Is it possible to find a bijective isometry?

Comment: You meant polynomials of degree at most n-1?

Comment: Did you mean $\max_{x\in[0,1]} |p(x)|$ rather than $\max_{x\in[0,1]} p(x) \text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: thanks for pointing out the mistakes in my original post. I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant polynomial of degree at most $n-1.$ And, I also feel, you meant absolute maximum, to be your norm.

Can of find extreme points of the unit ball of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the space you mentioned. Note that number of extreme points is "something" preserved under isometric isomorphism.